# Lesbegue Outer Measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Consider the unit interval $I=[0,1]$ and let $\mathcal{M}$ be the $\sigma$-algebra of all Lebesgue measurable subsets of $I$. Denote by $m_*$ the Lebesgue outer measure on $\mathcal{M}$. Suppose that $E \subset I$ such that $m_*(E)=1$. Prove that if $A,B \in \mathcal{M}$ and $A\cap E=B\cap E$, then $m(A)=m(B)$.

So I started of using the following idea:
$E\backslash A=E\backslash B$. Using the incision property $m(E)-m(A)=m(E)-m(B)$, so $m(A)=m(B)$.

I am not too sure if that is right. I need some clarification on what to do? Is there any other way I could approach this problem?

Comment: Why is $E - A = E - B$?  Also, why is $m(E - A) = m(E) - m(A)$?  Isn't this only true if $A \subseteq E$?  Otherwise, $m(E - A) = m(E) - m(E \cap A)$.

Comment: @user46944.... Suppose E is a subset of the interval [0,1] such that m*(E)=1. If A is a subset [0,1] and b is a subset of [0,1], doesnt it suffix to say that E\A=E\B?

Comment: It does?  Let $A = \{ \frac{1}{4}  \}$ and $B = \{ \frac{3}{4}  \}$.  Both $A$ and $B$ are Lebesgue measurable.  Take $E = [0,1]$.  Is $E - A$ equal to $E - B$?  This counterexample doesn't have the property that $A \cap B = B \cap E$.  Are you using that property in any way to say $E - A = E - B$?

Comment: @user46944... No, it is not equal. So what do you suggest as the start-off point? I have been battling with this for the past hour even though it appears trivial?

Comment: Is the assumption really $A \cap B = B \cap E$ or is it $A \cap E = B \cap E$? Because $B =\emptyset$, $A$ arbitrary of positive measure gives a counterexample.

Comment: @PhoemueX... it should be A$\cap$E=B$\cap$E. Thanks for correcting. Why is B empty?

Comment: I just meant that the formulation as before can not be true, because if we **take** $B = \emptyset$ and $A$ arbitrary of positive measure, then this yields a counterexample to the original formulation.

Comment: I allowed myself to correct the formulation of the problem according to your comment (i.e. I replaced $A \cap B = B\cap E$ by $A \cap E = B \cap E$).

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to show that $m^\ast(A\cap E) = m(A)$ for all measurable sets $A$, because this will yield $m(A) = m^\ast (A\cap E) = m^\ast (B\cap E) = m(B)$.

To see this, note that $m^\ast (A\cap E) \leq m^\ast (A) = m(A)$, so that we can assume (toward a contradiction) that $m^\ast (A \cap E) < m(A)$.

By definition of $m^\ast$, there is some countable family $(I_n)_n$ of measurable sets (usually intervals, depending on the exact defnition of $m^\ast$) with $A \cap E \subset \bigcup_n I_n$ and such that $\sum_n m(I_n) < m(A)$.

Let $\varepsilon := \frac{1}{2} \cdot (m(A) - \sum_n m(I_n)) > 0$. Then, there is also a countable family $(J_n)$ covering $A^c = [0,1] \setminus A$ such that $\sum_n m(J_n) < m(A^c) + \varepsilon = 1 - m(A) + \varepsilon$.

This shows $$E = (A \cap E) \cup (A^c \cap E) \subset \bigcup_n I_n \cup A^c \subset \bigcup_n I_n \cup \bigcup_n J_n$$

and hence

$$
m^\ast (E) \leq \sum_n m(I_n) + \sum_n m(J_n) < \sum_n m(I_n) + (1 - m(A) + \varepsilon) = 1 -2 \varepsilon + \varepsilon < 1, 
$$
a contradiction.

Comment: @PhoemueX....This is insightful and well explained. Thanks for letting me see this from a different perspective.